# How can i pass an object from one class to another in WPF (MVVM)?

Tags: wpf, object, mvvm

I´m learning the MVVM for WPF. I know how to rout events and split the Code in View, ViewModel, Model. I have in my main-XAML a TabControl and have split the tabs into different views.
My Question is, how can i pass an object from one class to another? (From the MainWindow.cs to the SubWindow.cs)

MainWindowRessources XAML:

```
....
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SubWindow}">
  <vw:SubWindow />
</DataTemplate>

<vm:SubWindow x:Key="subView" />
..
```

MainWindow XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary Source="MainWindowResources.xaml" />
</Window.Resources>

...
..
<TabItem>
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource subView}" />
</TabItem>
...
..
```

Comment: It is Model, View and ViewModel.  There is no ModelView.  You probably need to get your concepts right.  If your concepts are wrong, then your code is wrong.

Comment: Pass an object from the MainViewModel to SubViewModel, using a constructor or a property setter.

Comment: MVVM means never having to say "mainwindow.cs".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider implementing the mediator pattern to allow your view models to communicate with each other.

See [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328660/sql-wpf-xaml-c-binding-data-dynamic-resource-accessing-to-non-static-data/4329444#4329444) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context/use, you could create a `DependencyProperty` on the `SubWindow` class, and pass the object as a parameter, ala `<vm:SubWindow MyNewProperty="some-value-or-object here"/>`.

Info about creating DependencyProperties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx

What is the object you're wanting to pass?

Comment: at the beginning i think a custom class or a XElement (xml)