# Binding data items on second window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, caliburn.micro

Finally I decided to jump on the WPF bandwagon and decided to follow the MVVM Pattern to create my applications. I am also using Caliburn.Micro.

I found many examples of Binding data to Windows but all the examples contained just one MainWindow. I couldn't figure out how to reference and make the binding when opening a second and third window. To illustrate my problem I created a simple application. This application has two windows, the main one named ShellView and the second one named Window1View. All I need in this application is to display the content of myStr1 into the TextBox on Window1View.

Here is the code:

**Views.ShellView.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Test.Views.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Title" />
        <Button Content="Window 1" Height="31" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,268,0,0" Name="btnWin1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="87" Click="btnWin1_click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Views.ShellView.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Test.Views
{
    using System.Windows;

    public partial class ShellView : Window
    {
        public ShellView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnWin1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window1View win1 = new Window1View();
            win1.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModels.ShellViewModel.cs**

```
namespace Test.ViewModels
{
    using Caliburn.Micro;

    public class ShellViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        public static string txt1 = "String 1";
        public static string txt2 = "String 2";

        private string title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return title; }
            set
            {
                if (title != value)
                {
                    title = value;
                    RaisePropertyChangedEventImmediately("Title");
                }
            }
        }

        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Hello Caliburn.Micro";
        }
    }
}
```

**Views.Window1View.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Test.Views.Window1View"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro"
        Title="Window 1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="TextBox 1" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,40,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        <TextBox Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,39,0,0" Name="txtBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Text="{Binding myStr1}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**View.Window1View.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Test.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1View.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1View : Window
    {
        public Window1View()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModels.Window1ViewModel.cs**

```
namespace Test.ViewModels
{
    class Window1ViewModel
    {
        public Window1ViewModel()
        {
            myStr1 = ShellViewModel.txt1;
        }

        public string myStr1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Bootstrapper.cs**

```
namespace Test
{
    public class Bootstrapper : Caliburn.Micro.Bootstrapper<Test.ViewModels.ShellViewModel>
    {
    }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Class="Test.App">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Test
{
    using System.Windows;

    public partial class App : Application
    {
        Bootstrapper bootstrapper;

        public App()
        {
            bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Carmelo

Comment: Wth, man/woman. If you want people to see the whole project just upload a zipped file somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something because I'm not familiar with Caliburn.Micro, but I see a couple of things going on here.

First, I don't see anywhere that you're setting the `DataContext` of the `Window1View` to be an instance of `Window1ViewModel`.

Second, your `Window1ViewModel` doesn't derive from `PropertyChangedBase` and you don't call `RaisePropertyChanged` when you change the myStr1 property.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to implement view model communication in MVVM is to use the [Mediator Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328660/sql-wpf-xaml-c-binding-data-dynamic-resource-accessing-to-non-static-data/4329444#4329444). Most MVVM frameworks include a 'Messenger' class that allows you to decouple your design by publishing and subscribing to events. In Caliburn Micro, mediation is supported by the [EventAggregator](http://sonyarouje.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/an-introduction-to-caliburn-micro/) class.

Since you are new to MVVM, I would also recommend the following resources:

- [Implementing the MVVM Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx)
- [Advanced MVVM Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx)
- [User Interaction Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx#sec10)

Comment: Oppositional, I will definetly look into the Mediator Pattern you mentioned. And thanks for the resources as well.

Answer (score 0):

A few things here:

1. You are using code behind unnecessarily. Ideally you should aim for virtually no code behind when using MVVM. Instead of creating a `btnWin1_click` handler, name the button and implement a method on your view model with the same name. Caliburn.Micro will invoke the view model method based on convention.
2. Use x:Name rather than Name
3. When displaying the `Window1ViewModel`, you are not using Caliburn.Micro to invoke the window display. This means that no binding exists between your `Window1View` and `Window1ViewModel`. If this is a separate window, use the `WindowManager` type from Caliburn.Micro. Instantiate your `Window1ViewModel`, and use the `WindowManager` class to display it. Caliburn.Micro will locate the appropriate view based on conventions, and bind the view to your view model.
4. As mentioned, rather than reference the `ShellViewModel` directly in the `Window1ViewModel` (which couples the view models and makes `Window1ViewModel` less reuseable), use the mediator pattern. Caliburn.Micro comes with an [EventAggregator](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator) class - you can publish the change in text from the `ShellViewModel`, and subscribe to the event in your `Window1ViewModel`.

Comment: Checkout the 3 series article by Rob starting here to understand how screen navigation works. http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2010/10/08/caliburn-micro-soup-to-nuts-part-6a-screens-conductors-and-composition.aspx. Also check the samples that are part of the caliburn download.

Comment: Thanks devdigital, your reply has cleared the fog a good deal. I will try to get my example code working according to your advice.